# Coordinator Layout implementation doesn't work

Tags: android, android-fragments

Couple of days I'm trying to implement coordinator layout but still stuck.
I have an activity that includes Toolbar and Navigationview,which is common through out my application,its a single window app where the fragment checkin and checkout.
Basically my question is how to implement Coordinator layout that works only for one fragment and rest of the fragment without coordinatorlayout.I 'm attaching my activity layout and fragments.
Any suggestion will be appreciated!!

acivity.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="right">

    <include
        layout="@layout/co_ordinator_base"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_sliding_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_menu">

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Fragment1.xml

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary">
        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/viewPager">
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get detailed answer at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html
and
http://www.androidauthority.com/using-coordinatorlayout-android-apps-703720/ here's also a tutorial that you can follow.
hope this helps